# Is <service>.amazonaws.com a user or a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

## Question

What is the .amazonaws.com such as elastictranscoder.amazonaws.com?

```
statement {
  sid    = "1"
  effect = "Allow"

  principals {
    identifiers = ["elastictranscoder.amazonaws.com"]
    type        = "Service"
  }
  actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
}
```

According to [Roles Terms and Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html), it should be either IAM user or a role. I wonder which one it is.

> Principal
> An entity in AWS that can perform actions and access resources. A ***principal** can be an AWS account root user, an IAM user, or a role*.
>
> Trust policy
> A document in JSON format in which you define who is allowed to assume the role. This trusted entity is included in the policy as the **principal element** in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither.  That definition is incomplete.

It's an AWS Service (type = "Service").

> Use the Principal element to specify the user (IAM user, federated user, or assumed-role user), AWS account, **AWS service**, or other principal entity that is allowed or denied access to a resource. *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html